# Swift How do I add a pdf file in my app's resource bundle prior to launching?

Tags: swift, bundle

I watched https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10169/ to see if I could add a pdf in an application's xcassets folder, but I had no luck. Is there a way to add a non-image file (e.g. pdf) into an application's resource bundle prior to launch?

Comment: You can simply add it to the project and it will be copied into the app bundle, then you can use `Bundle.main.urlForResource...` to retrieve it's location and then it's `Data`.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Thank you so much for your quick reply. So do I add it in the same folder as the one right below project_name.xcodeproj?

Comment: I'm currently using the app delegate life cycle, so I currently have four folders, project_name, project_nameTests, project_nameUITests, and Products. Which one of these folders should I add the pdf to?

Comment: Add it to project_name, you can also create a new folder in project_name and add the file to it if you want to separate it from the code files